# JSTL continue, break inside foreach

Tags: jsp, foreach, jstl

I want to insert "continue" inside foreach in JSTL. Please let me know if there is a way to achieve this.

```
<c:forEach 
  var="List"
  items="${requestScope.DetailList}" 
  varStatus="counter"
  begin="0">

  <c:if test="${List.someType == 'aaa' || 'AAA'}">
    <<<continue>>>
  </c:if>
```

I want to insert the "continue" inside the if condition.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There's no such thing. Just do the inverse for the content you *actually* want to display. So don't do

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.DetailList}" var="list">
    <c:if test="${list.someType eq 'aaa' or list.someType eq 'AAA'}">
        <<<continue>>>
    </c:if>
    <p>someType is not aaa or AAA</p>
</c:forEach>
```

but rather do

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.DetailList}" var="list">
    <c:if test="${not (list.someType eq 'aaa' or list.someType eq 'AAA')}">
        <p>someType is not aaa or AAA</p>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

or

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.DetailList}" var="list">
    <c:if test="${list.someType ne 'aaa' and list.someType ne 'AAA'}">
        <p>someType is not aaa or AAA</p>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Please note that I fixed an EL syntax error in your code as well.

Comment: +1 aah - now I understand why she wanted to use continue. Good interpretation of the question BalusC!

Comment: I cant do the inverse. Because, I do some actions under the loop. I wanted to stop that if this condition pass. I want to go for the next iteration if this condition passes. Thanks for your answer. I'll try to go with another logic if there is no way of making it to next iteration with continue.

Comment: I made the condition inverse and it works fine now. Thanks a lot for your replies and interest in support.

Answer (score 5):

I solved it using Set at the end of my executable code and inside of the loop

```
<c:set var="continueExecuting" scope="request" value="false"/>
```

then I used that variable to skip the execution of the code in the next iteration using

```
<c:if test="${continueExecuting}">
```

you can set it back to true at any time...

```
<c:set var="continueExecuting" scope="request" value="true"/>
```

more on this tag at: [JSTL Core  Tag](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_set_tag.htm)

enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use EL ***choose*** statement

```
<c:forEach 
      var="List"
      items="${requestScope.DetailList}" 
      varStatus="counter"
      begin="0">

      <c:choose>
         <c:when test="${List.someType == 'aaa' || 'AAA'}">
           <!-- continue -->
         </c:when>
         <c:otherwise>
            Do something...     
         </c:otherwise>
      </c:choose>
    </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this idea of having the variable on the foreach, and setting it to the end of the loop to exit with a c:set ... if you structure a begin and an end for loop.

https://www.codesenior.com/en/tutorial/How-To-Break-Foreach-Loop-in-JSP