# Break method in JSTL

Tags: jstl, el

Does JSTL suuports  a break method?I search on the web and i didn't found a good answer.Is it possible tou do something like this:

```
<c:if test="${fn:contains(data, 'apple')}">
    <break>
</c:if>
```

Comment: You may want to conditionally transfer a control out of a loop rather than (breaking) a method, I think.

Comment: You may want to see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578420/jstl-continue-break-inside-foreach).

Comment: I saw almost all the questions at stackoverflow for this issue. I just want to see if there is an integration of the JSTL with smt else for the break method. That's i'm trying to find  out

Comment: Then you might achieve the same using custom tags. JSTL is basically designed for some kind of expressions only.

Comment: What exactly is the concrete functional requirement? Is this inside a `<c:forEach>` or so?

Answer (score 0):

JSTL does not support a `break` statment or tag, unless until the version 1.1. You can see a list of all tags and functions in the [doc page](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/).

You will have to play with a boolean variable in the `test` condition to archive a similar behaviour.