# How can i break or continue the foreach loop in JSP

Tags: jsp

How can i break or continue the for each loop in JSP

```
<c:set var="count" value="0" scope="page" />
```

Here In for each loop

```
<c:set var="count" value="${count + 1}" scope="page" />
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="count == 2" > <break> </c:when>
    <c:otherwise> <continue> </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

It doesn't work here.....Please help.....Thank you

Comment: There is no break or continue in `foreach` loop. Refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578420/jstl-continue-break-inside-foreach for a workaround

Comment: you can use `<c:forEach begin="0" end="1" var="count">`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to evaluate a scriptlet variable in EL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965812/how-to-evaluate-a-scriptlet-variable-in-el)