# How we can terminate the JSTL loop?

Tags: jstl

```
<c:forEach var="list" items="${dptList}">
   <c:if test="${list.deptNo==30}">
    [i want here iteration should stop and exit the loop after matching the condition]
   </c:if>
   <label>${list.deptNo}</label>
   <label>${list.deptname}</label>
</c:forEach>
```

How i can terminate the iteration eg. if deptNo is 30

Comment: where is your JSTL loop?

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible to break a `c:forEach` like this. The cleanest way would be to filter the list before passing it to the JSP. This logic is about more than just the way of displaying the data, it's a matter of what data is returned so I'd keep it out of the presentation layer.

Comment: @toniedzwiedz but if there is such requirement which must be filter on presentation layer due to depending on user selection....at that time how we can terminate from iterating the if there is thousands of record?

Comment: I don't know the architecture of your application but if you have to filter thousands of records in a JSP, something is wrong. What if you're required to serve the same data in a different format at some point (JSON or XML)?

Comment: Any interaction of the user with your JSP requires an HTTP call anyway. The user does not interact with the JSP itself but with an entire back-end that uses JSP as a way to render an HTML page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSTL continue, break inside foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578420/jstl-continue-break-inside-foreach)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `break` or `continue` in the `JSTL` library.

The easiest way would be to filter your list in the controller.

If you can't, you can use a temporary variable:

```
<c:set var="done" value="false" />

<c:forEach var="list" items="${dptList}">
   <c:if test="${list.deptNo==30}">
      <c:set var="done" value="true" />
   </c:if>
   <c:if test="${!done}">
      <label>${list.deptNo}</label>
      <label>${list.deptname}</label>
   </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but its not worth actually..i know there is no break command but my motive was that if we use JSTL loop then how we can terminate and exit the loop on a specific result or any condition so that it could not iterate till the end of record.